# reading file with UPC

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc, upc

I'm starting to learn UPC, and I have the following piece of code to read a file:

```
upc_file_t *fileIn;
int n;
fileIn = upc_all_fopen("input_small", UPC_RDONLY | UPC_INDIVIDUAL_FP , 0, NULL);
upc_all_fread_local(fileIn, &n, sizeof(int), 1, UPC_IN_ALLSYNC | UPC_OUT_ALLSYNC);

upc_barrier;
printf("%d\n", n);

upc_all_fclose(fileIn);
```

However, the output (value of n) is always 808651319, which means something is wrong, and I can't find what is it. The first line of the file I'm giving as input is '7', so the result of the `printf` should be 7...

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPC Parallel I/O library performs unformatted (binary) input/output, not formatted one like what you get with `(f)printf(3)`/`(f)scanf(3)` from the standard C library. Parallel I/O cannot handle text files because of their intrinsic properties like variable-length records.

```
upc_all_fread_local(fileIn, &n, sizeof(int), 1, UPC_IN_ALLSYNC | UPC_OUT_ALLSYNC)
```

behaves like the following call to the standard C library function for unformatted read from a file:

```
fread(&n, sizeof(int), 1, fh)
```

You are just reading 1 element of `sizeof(int)` bytes from the file (4 bytes on most platforms) into the address of `n`. The number you got `808651319` in hexadecimal is `0x30330A37`. On little endian systems like x86/x64 this is stored in memory and on disk as `0x37 0x0A 0x33 0x30` (reversed byte order). These are the ASCII codes of the first 4 bytes of the string `7\n30` (`\n` or LF is the line feed/new line symbol) so I'd guess your `input_small` file looked like:

```
7
30...
...
```

You should prepare your input data in *binary format* using `fwrite(3)` instead of using `(f)printf(3)` or your text editor of choice.